# Find date in specific group which is next to current group avoiding undesired groups

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume table called t1:

```
create table t1(
    dates date,
    groups number
);

insert into t1 values('01.03.2020', 1);
insert into t1 values('02.03.2020', 2);
insert into t1 values('10.03.2020', 3);
insert into t1 values('01.04.2020', 10);
insert into t1 values('02.04.2020', 20);
insert into t1 values('10.04.2020', 3);

DATES       GROUPS
01.03.2020  1
02.03.2020  2
10.03.2020  3
01.04.2020  10
02.04.2020  20
10.04.2020  3
```

I need to add column which would store value from DATES column where GROUP column value equals to 3 and that should be date of nearest 3d group in term of time.

Desired result:

```
DATES       GROUPS  DATE_OF_NEXT_3D_GROUP
01.03.2020  1       10.03.2020
02.03.2020  2       10.03.2020
10.03.2020  3       NULL(or could be 10.04.2020 from next 3d group)
01.04.2020  10      10.04.2020
02.04.2020  20      10.04.2020
10.04.2020  3       NULL(or date from next 3d group)
...         ...     ...
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly, strongly recommend using analytic functions for this rather than a correlated subquery:

```
select dates, groups,
       (case when groups <> 3
             then min(case when groups = 3 then dates end) over (order by dates desc)
        end)
from t1
order by 1;
```

Analytic functions are designed for this type of operation and should have much better performance.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=50ba63e88a667778cecb7a35d4113654) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a subquery:

```sql
select dates,
       groups,
       (select min(dates)
          from t1 b
         where b.groups = 3
           and b.dates > a.dates) as next_g3_date
  from t1 a;
```